# Repeat a string while avoiding a space on the end

Tags: ruby

I was wondering how I can get rid of a space at the end of a string. I'm trying to make a repeat method that repeats a string a certain amount of times using default values. This is what I have so far.

```
    def repeat(word, num = 2)
      num.times do
        print word + " " 
      end
    end

    repeat("hello")
```

I need this to give me "hello hello" but it gives me "hello hello " with the space. How can I get rid of that extra space? I tried chop but I can't seem to implement it right.

Comment: FYI [`strip`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-strip) removes leading & trailing whitespace from a string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def repeat(word, num = 2)
  print ([word] * num).join(" ")
end

repeat("hello")
```

Comment: Ok, so here you made an array with word and multiplied it by num then you joined a space between each word in the array. This fixes my problem thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you assign a new string to your repeat method you can use [chop!](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-chop-21).

It will modify the string in place, removing the last space you have.  Before, calling `chop` will return a copy of the string thus leaving the space you had.

Try doing:

```
chopped = repeat("hello").chop!
```

Comment: @diedthreetimes Does a String have trim?  I was just pointing out to the poster that he used the method that returns a copy rather than in place, which is why it didn't work for him.

Comment: wow, I actually meant strip. You are correct in that he wasn't using the in-place method. I was just pointing out you could also use strip. Also, it would probably be best to chop the string at the end of repeat before the method returns. Then you wouldn't need the bang version at all.

Comment: @diedthreetimes As they say in Perl, there is more than one way to do it :).

Answer (score 0):

One more option:

```
def repeat(word, num = 2)
  print ("#{word} " * num).strip
end
```